# How to retrieve category attribute of a test fixture using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit, system.reflection, nunit-3.0

I have an NUnit test project. In that I have a class like this

```
    [TestFixture]
    [Category("A")]
    public class SmokeTest
    {

    }
```

If you notice, the class has a Category attribute which is mentioned as Category("A").
I want to retrieve the value of the category attribute using reflection. For that, I am trying the code below:

```
public void MyMethod()
{           
     Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("dllpath");
     var types = executingAssembly.GetTypes();
     foreach (Type type in types)
     {
       var testFixtureAttrList = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(type, typeof(TestFixtureAttribute));
       if (testFixtureAttrList.Length > 0)
       {
CategoryAttribute[] categoryAttributes = (CategoryAttribute[])Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(type, typeof(CategoryAttribute));
           foreach (CategoryAttribute attribute in categoryAttributes)
           {
               Console.WriteLine($"CategoryAttribute :: Name: {attribute.Name}");

           }//FOR-EACH ENDS
      }
   }
}
```

But, so far I have not been able to retrieve the category attribute using this code. So, what should I do to retrieve the Category attribute ?

My code is written in C#. My solution is built using .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler...

Categories are available to you in the `TestContext` when running the `OneTimeSetUp` method...

```
...
IEnumerable<CategoryAttribute> fixtureCategories;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void MyOneTimeSetUpMethod()
{
    fixtureCategories =
        TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Category"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    string dllPath = @"C:\Path\To\Dll.dll";

    Type[] types = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath).GetTypes();

    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
        IEnumerable<TestFixtureAttribute> textFixtures = type.GetCustomAttributes<TestFixtureAttribute>();

        if (textFixtures.Any())
        {
            IEnumerable<CategoryAttribute> categories = type.GetCustomAttributes<CategoryAttribute>();

            foreach (CategoryAttribute category in categories)
                Console.WriteLine($"Type: {type}; CategoryAttribute :: Name: {category.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

Or even shorter version without checking TextFixtureAttribute:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    string dllPath = @"C:\Path\To\Dll.dll";

    Type[] types = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath).GetTypes();

    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
        IEnumerable<CategoryAttribute> categories = type.GetCustomAttributes<CategoryAttribute>();

        foreach (CategoryAttribute category in categories)
            Console.WriteLine($"Type: {type}; CategoryAttribute :: Name: {category.Name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working. I have tried your solution. I am not able to retrieve the category attribute of a fixture.

Comment: Well, I would say classic: it works on my machine. Are you looking in correct dll? Did you build all your projects?

Comment: I figured out the issue. I was giving the wrong dll path. Now, it is working fine.